# How do I draw this solid in Mathematica with the given f(x,y) and r(t)?

Tags: plotting

$$\begin{align*}
f(x,y)&=1+y^2\\
\mathbf r(t)&=2\cos t\,\mathbf i+2\sin t\,\mathbf j,\qquad 0\le t\le 2\pi
\end{align*}$$

[image]

How do I draw the solid shown above given the $f(x,y)$ and $r(t)$ provided?

Comment: Maybe `Plot3D[1 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5, 0.5], Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]`. There's also `ParametricPlot3D` if you prefer more control.

Comment: Michael's code is the best thing to do, but the straightforward translation is something like `Plot3D[1 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ ParametricRegion[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {{r, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2 π}}], Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5, 0.5], Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]`. I'll let someone else fiddle with the styling.

Comment: Both these solutions are great. How would you use ParametricPlot3D to draw this solid? @Michael E2

Answer (score 2):

Following the comments under the question I made a summary of three proposed solutions:

**Michael E2's `Plot3D` solution:**

```
Plot3D[1+y^2,{x,y}∈Disk[{0,0},2],
  Mesh->None,PlotStyle->GrayLevel[0.5,0.5],Filling->Axis,
  PlotRange->{0,Automatic},BoxRatios->Automatic
]
```

> [image: First Plot3D]

**J. M.'s slightly less busy's `Plot3D` solution:**

```
Plot3D[1+y^2,{x,y}∈
  ParametricRegion[{r Cos[t],r Sin[t]},{{r,0,2},{t,0,2 π}}],
  Mesh->None,PlotStyle->GrayLevel[0.5,0.5],
  Filling->Axis,PlotRange->{0,Automatic},BoxRatios->Automatic
]
```

> [image: Second Plot3D]

**An implementation based on two `ParametricPlot3D` (as proposed by Michael E2?):**

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[{2Cos[ϕ],2Sin[ϕ],z},{ϕ,0,2π},{z,0,6},
    RegionFunction->({x,y,z}|->z<1+y^2),Mesh->None,
    PlotStyle->GrayLevel[0.5,0.5]],
  ParametricPlot3D[{x,y,1+y^2},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},
    RegionFunction->({x,y,z}|->x^2+y^2<=2^2),
    Mesh->None,PlotStyle->GrayLevel[0.5,0.5],
    BoundaryStyle->Black]
}]
```

> [image: ParametricPlot3D]

Answer (score 2):

Improve the plot by `RegionFunction`.

```
f[x_, y_] = 1 + y^2; 
Plot3D[{f[x, y], 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 2]], 
 PlotStyle -> Gray, Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Accent", 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Filling -> Axis, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 FillingStyle -> Gray, ViewPoint -> {-2.87, -1.26, 1.25}]
```

[image]